# Can we use multiple OneToOneFields in single User Model? Any performance issue happen?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django, I'm working on a project. I have define User model with multiple parts.

User
   --> default property like username, email, password, date_joined, is_staff, is_superadmin...

UserProfile
   --> OneToOneField(User), first_name, last_name, gender, avatar, dob.

UserPhoneAuth
   --> OneToOneField(User), otp_code, etc..

UserEmailAuth
   --> OneToOneField(User), secret_key, etc...

UserCard
   --> OneToOneField(User), card_name, card_no, etc..

UserWallet
   --> OneToOneField(User), chips, tokens.

Is this best practice to split multiple models?. Any one can please help me on this.

Advanced Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are doing with the users.
So if you create a phone OTP twice a day or not.
If u do it may be better handled in the way u propose, but if OTP is just for registration keep it in user model (this is my logic - maybe u think otherwize).

It is always something to think about.
Look at my example to start with

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        # do stuff
        user.save()
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        # do stuff
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        return user


class User(AbstractUser):

    objects = UserManager()

    is_physician = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True,)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True,)
    home_phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, null=True)

# Now, lets say u need another entity (IDK why or what ...) say an assistant 
class Assistant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,)
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_nurse = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So if the assistant has special fields like is_archived or is_nurse i would put it in that model if it reflects all users i would put it in USER model

Comment: Thanks for your response, As i mention users model we will get any performance issue?. You know what is the django best practices?

Comment: As i mentioned it depends :)